# How to POST data from node js to codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, codeigniter

I am trying to send the data from node.js to PHP codeigniter to implement in my project I tried this by using the code I have given below but the data is not receiving in the codeigniter function can anyone help me on this one? Thanks

My codeigniter controller function:

```php
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST);
```

My node js code:

```
var request = require('request');
var http = require('http');
var post_body = {
    pos1: '10',
    pos2: '15'
};
var post_body_json = JSON.stringify(post_body);
var post_options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    path: '/govtech/pab/branches/testing/index.php/websocket/node_data',
    body: post_body_json,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Super Agent/0.0.1',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
}; 
var post_req = http.request(post_options, function (res) {
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
        });
    });

    post_req.end();
```

Comment: I guess your content type is wrong, try this: 'content-type': 'application/json'

Comment: Your controller is doing something it shouldn't. Since your nodeJS code is already submitting a form via `POST` you shouldn't assign a value to your `$_POST` superglobal, just read from it. Use CI's form helper to read the POSTed data with `$this->input->post('field_name')` and you're set. (but don't forget to run form validations and sanitizing the input first... don't ever trust the users)

Comment: Also, this `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); ` won't ever work. You are running to separate statements here. You are just echoing `<pre>` until the first semicolon. Then, `print_r` is not getting printed or echoed to the screen. Try `echo "<pre>". print_r($_POST); `

Comment: I tried to get the values directly by using $this->input->post('field_name') but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer we have to change the `POST` method to `GET` method.

Updated controller code:

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($_GET);
```

Updated node js code:

```
var request = require('request');
var http = require('http');
var post_body = {
    pos1: '10',
    pos2: '15'
};
var post_body_json = JSON.stringify(post_body);
var post_options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    path: '/govtech/pab/branches/testing/index.php/websocket/node_data',
    body: post_body_json,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Super Agent/0.0.1',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
}; 
var post_req = http.request(post_options, function (res) {
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
        });
    });

    post_req.end();
```